# why no notifications are sent when irc message matches keywords in ERC?

Tags: emacs, irc

I am using ERC in emacs 24 and using the following code in my `.emacs`. The `erc-global-notify` function is adapted from http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ErcPageMe. Unfortunately, I couoldn't get any notifcations from dbus when the emacs with erc windows is minimized. What's the problem with it?

```
(require 'erc-match)
(erc-match-mode t)
(setq erc-keywords '("c++" "python" "emacs" "i")
      erc-pals '("ij"  "yy" "xx"))

(require 'notifications)
(defun erc-global-notify (match-type nick message)
  "Notify when someone sends a message that matches a regexp in `erc-keywords'."
  (when (and (eq match-type 'keyword)
             ;; I don't want to see anything from the erc server
             (null (string-match "^[sS]erver" nick))
             ;; or bots
             (null (string-match "\\(bot\\|serv\\)!" nick)))
    (notifications-notify
     :title nick
     :body message
     :urgency 'normal)))

(add-hook 'erc-text-matched-hook 'erc-global-notify)
```